# Where is my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am playing around with a new MVC 3 project with entity framwork 4.1.  When I use the registration I can see my data by going into the server explorer in VS.  Now I created my own model and a context for storing that data.  My problem is that I do not know where this database actually is or how I can view it in the server explorer?  I know this data is being stored somewhere because it is there each time I run the app.  If this question is not clear please ask any question that will make it easier to understand.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Either hosted somewhere or it's in your App_Data folder. Can you post a connection string without any private data in it from web.config?

Comment: It has the basic connection string that the default project has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it is stored in your App_Data folder (if you created ASP.NET MVC 3 application with forms authentication).